# How to read an existing TimeStamp?

Tags: java, json, timestamp

I am working on somebody else's code and am getting a JSON-Object with an existing TimeStamp:

```
"lastModification": 1582013867500
```

Well, I am struggling to read this. I checked the TimeStamp docs but still I don't know how to read that.
Can anybody help?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to convert this to human-readable Date format?

Comment: No I want to update the object with a new timestamp. But first I want to understand the schema

Comment: Unix epoch or POSIX time or Unix timestamp - number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970. Your current timestamp is in milliseconds.

Comment: Exactly what @J-Alex commented, the value of your example millis is `2020-02-18T08:17:47.5Z` (UTC)

Comment: Oh yeah u r right. May you post that an answer so I can mark it as right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix epoch or POSIX time or Unix timestamp - number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970.

Your current timestamp is written in milliseconds.

You can use conversion tools to read it online, like https://www.epochconverter.com/.

Java Time library supports both seconds and milliseconds conversions:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(lastModification),
                        TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());

// OR using ZoneId

LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(lastModification),
                        ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(lastModification),
                        ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 2):

This *timestamp* is a moment in time since January 1st, 1970, represented in milliseconds.

You can make it readable using a little `java.time` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long millis = 1582013867500L;
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

The output is

```
2020-02-18T08:17:47.5Z
```